# MikroORM doesn't parse JSON property on Ubuntu

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

We are using simple json properties to store custom data types as json within a mariaDB database using mikroORM:

```
@Property({ type: 'json' })
field: DataType;
```

On my local machine (macOS Big Sur 11.6) everything works as expected. On my co developers machine (Windows 10) and within Docker containers everything works fine.

Yesterday as a test we deployed the project directly to a Linux server running Ubuntu 20.4 without using Docker containers. For some reason mikroORM doesn't serialise the json on that machine and just returns the unparsed string instead. This happens to all json properties in the project.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this issue?